# JQuery simulate enter on input field

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, enter, inputbox

I've got a form, where i put information in with greasemonkey.
The form got no ID or Class...

When you manauly put something in the inputbox, and press enter, it get's submitted and you're off... I want to achief the same with jquery.

Changing the value's of the input boc is not the problem, but submitting.

Ive got the following code;

```
e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    e.which = 13;
    e.keyCode = 13;
    $("#inputy").focus();
    $("#inputy").trigger(e);
```

But this doesn't work... So how does i simulate an enter in the inputbox with the ID inputy?

Greetz
TWCrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to submit the form? You can try:

```
$("#inputy").keyup( function( event )
{
    if(event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        var form = $( "#inputy" ).closest( "form" );
        form.submit( );
    }
});
```

On every key-up we check for the `Enter` key. If the `Enter` key was released we then find the closest form and submit it.

Comment: problem... I'm adding the data to the form dynamicly with jqeury... So when i add the data, i want to submit. Not adding the data with jqeury, and pressing enter by myself...

Comment: Ah. Then whenever you are done adding the data, can you not call `form.submit( )`? If you don't know the form itself, just use `.closest( "form" )` on whatever the last field you added data to.

Answer (score 0):

Probably pressing enter on `<input>` fire `submit()` method on entire `<form>` so try do it  after you fill up your `<input>` using following method: `$("form").submit()`.

Anyway, is there `jquery` for sure on that site? Are there any errors on console?

Comment: As menthiod above, i don't want to press the enter button by myself, i want to do it with jquery. And yes, Jquery is permitted and no errors.

Comment: I mean use jquery method `$("form").submit()` , word `manually` was my mistake :)

Comment: haha, could always happen ;P ssell have answerd my question already, but thanks for your opinion ;P. And that would probally not work, because there more forms on the site, so i wouldn't work unless i added closest (damm wat am i learning today :P)